# tf tutorial:cannot launch node of type

Tags: ros, roslaunch, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When following the tf tutorial,there are errors here:
After typing "roslaunch turtle_tf_broadcaster start_demo.launch",
it returns
"ERROR: cannot launch node of type [learning_tf/turtle_tf_broadcaster]: can't locate node [turtle_tf_broadcaster] in package [learning_tf]"
How can I correct it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74608/tf-tutorial:cannot-launch-node-of-type/) by [isnow4ever](https://answers.ros.org/users/6142/isnow4ever/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built with catkin and had the same problem. I solved it by executing the command "source devel/setup.sh" in the catkin workplace before running the launch file.
(I always forget to run it....)

---

Originally posted by [lguodongustc](https://answers.ros.org/users/10416/lguodongustc/) with karma: 61 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isnow4ever](https://answers.ros.org/users/6142/isnow4ever/) on 2014-03-06**:
Thanks! It's useful.